# How to join multiple tables using laravel eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Code

```
   function viewPDF()
{
    $reports = Report::join('president_report', 'reports.id', '=', 'president_report.report_id')
        ->join('president_report as pr', 'presidents.id', '=', 'pr.president_id')
        ->join('quarter_report', 'president_report.report_id', '=', 'quarter_report.report_id')
        ->filter()->latest()->get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.test1', ['reports' => $reports]);
    return $pdf->stream('reports.pdf');
}
```

Error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'presidents.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `reports` inner join `president_report` on `reports`.`id` = `president_report`.`report_id` inner join `president_report` as `pr` on `presidents`.`id` = `pr`.`president_id` inner join `quarter_report` on `president_report`.`report_id` = `quarter_report`.`report_id` order by `created_at` desc)
```

I want to do by Eloquent way. Please, how could I do?

**1-Table** `quarters`

```
Schema::create('quarters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('quarter_report', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('quarter_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('report_id')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(['quarter_id' , 'report_id']);
    });
```

**2- Table** `presidents`

```
Schema::create('presidents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->string('P_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
 Schema::create('president_report', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('president_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('report_id')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(['president_id','report_id']);
    });
```

**3- Table**  `reports`

```
Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('target_value');
        $table->text('major_activity');
        $table->string('indicator');
        $table->string('responsibility');
        $table->string('progress_activity');
        $table->string('documents')->nullable();
        $table->string('percentage_activity')->nullable();
        $table->text('problem')->nullable();
        $table->text('solution')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('0');
        $table->tinyInteger('active')->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

[I have 5 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkmX1.png)

Comment: Is your table related to each other?

Comment: hmm im quiet confused. Does your `Report` model, table name `presidents`?

Answer (score 0):

This is answer for [this version of question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58091633/1).

Try alias joining table as follows

```
->join('president_report as pr', 'presidents.id', '=', 'pr.president_id')
```

and/or instead `'pr.president_id'` use `DB::raw( 'pr.president_id' )`

Comment: I tried alias joining table as follows   `->join('president_report as pr', 'presidents.id', '=', 'pr.president_id') `   Error:  `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'presidents.id' `

Comment: @EzatullahTabish this column is in your original question query - I don't know why you use It and what is it's source - but the error changes so this mean that above solve error in your question - but it looks like your query contains more errors - if you have problem to solve them - try to find answer on stack overflow or create new question

Answer (score 0):

**use DB::raw()**

```
function viewPDF()
{
    $reports = Report::join('president_report','president_report.report_id' 'reports.id', '=', 'president_report.report_id')
        ->join('president_report as pr', DB::raw('presidents.id'), '=',DB::raw( 'pr.president_id'))
        ->join('quarter_report', 'president_report.report_id', '=', 'quarter_report.report_id')
        ->filter()->latest()->get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.test1', ['reports' => $reports]);
    return $pdf->stream('reports.pdf');
}
```

Comment: **I use DB::raw()**  `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.report_id join `president_report`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have built an relationship with your **models**

**(1) FIRST OPTION**

**CONTROLLER**

In your controller you can do like this.

```
President::with('president_report')->get()->map(function($president){
  return [
    'president_id' => $president->id,
    'president_report_id' => $president->president_report->id,
  ]
})
```

**(2) SECOND OPTION**

If you want to access the parent parent relationship.

> `quarters` belongs to `president_report` and `president_reports` belongs to `president`

You could do this.

**President MODEL**

```
public function quarters() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Quarter::class, President_report::class);
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

In your controller  you can do this.

```
$presidents = President::all();

$quaters = president->quarters()->where('quarters.report_id', 1)->get();

dd($quarters);
```